# I can't find the mistake in my php script

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to write a script in PHP that takes the current URL of the page, searches it in the database (phpMyAdmin with WAMP) and prints the ID of the row with that URL. I have written this, and to the point of the connection, everythwing works, the connection with mysql also works fine, the problem starts on this line:

```
 $query = "SELECT id FROM search WHERE link = '". $curPageURL . "'";
```

Can anyone please tell me: what Am I doing wrong? this is the whole script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

 <?php
 function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
 }
 echo curPageURL();

 //connection
 $con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Could not connect");
 mysql_select_db("search") or die ("Could not select db");
 echo "connection succesful";

 $query = "SELECT id FROM search WHERE link = '". $curPageURL . "'";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 echo $row;
 }
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It looks like you need to execute the query before you fetch data: [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: You don't have an (assigned) variable called `$curPageURL`, unless you're trying to pass/inject that similar function into it. Or, you meant to use `$pageURL`

Comment: "the problem starts on this line". What is your problem, precisely?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: and please use a more modern API like mysqli or PDO with prepared statements and placeholders.

Comment: Do you get any error? But I also bet in @showdev comment

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You're right, I changed it to $pageURL now, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Furthermore I'd suggest quoting the URL to avoid any issues with special characters: http://de1.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string or http://de1.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @user3599598 You don't have a variable `$pageURL` either. Only in the function scope. You probably want `$query = "SELECT id FROM search WHERE link = '". curPageURL() . "'";`.

Comment: these are the errors I'm getting:
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in C:\wamp\www\Get_url.php on line 10

http://localhost/Get_url.phpconnection succesful
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: PageURL in C:\wamp\www\Get_url.php on line 26


( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\Get_url.php on line 28

Comment: This one's a real humdinger. Hard to say what's what and what should go into where and how and from what. @jeroen

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's not that hard: the request is not a https request, so there's no $_SERVER['HTTPS'], thats the "Undefined index: HTTPS". Next comes the notice about $PageURL because of his change from $curPageURL (instead to curPageURL()). Last the missing mysql_query() ...

Answer (score 1):

You did not run the query with `mysql_query()` and you do not setou variable `$curPageURL`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

 <?php
 function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
 }
 echo curPageURL();

 //connection
 $con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Could not connect");
 mysql_select_db("search") or die ("Could not select db");
 echo "connection succesful";

 $query = "SELECT id FROM search WHERE link = '". curPageURL() . "'";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row;
 }
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Please note that the method you have used is deprecated from php 5.5.0. so i suggest you consider mysqli or PDO. examples can be found in below php manual links

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: What about `$curPageURL`?

Comment: As it stands, it's hard to say what the OP wants to use as the actual value. I'd wait it out in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this.

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM search WHERE link = '". curPageURL() . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped, now I'm getting this output: 
Array ( [0] => 4 [id] => 4 )

The ID is 4 so that's right, but how do I only get 4 as output, no more?

Comment: @user3599598 You should read up on how sql statements work. You select the id, you get the id.

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
I'd recommend not using the user root or a blank password, too. PDO is a great way to go, also, so you might want to look into that.
http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php