# How to only print the ID of this echo?

Tags: php, mysql

I want my code to output only one value — id. But I'm getting this as output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 21 
    [id] => 21 
)
```

instead of just '21'. How can I fix that?

This is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM search WHERE link = '". curPageURL() . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $idie = print_r($row);
    print $idie;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505568/i-cant-find-the-mistake-in-my-php-script/23505689#23505689
See my answer in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing out full array, but, to achieve what you want, you have to print one of elements of this array. Example below.

This will work:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $idie = $row['id'];
    print $idie;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was as simple as that!

Comment: @user3599598 it is good practise to accept answers if they are answers for your question (like in this case)

Comment: @user3599598 Any chance you'll accept my answer to your original version of this question?